# Apply JQuery to div's clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, class

I am working on making a number list with each number on its individual div. So far I am able to remove the div with Javascript (on click), but I would like to enable JQuery so that I am able to add a class to a div and then remove all divs of that class with a button or something like that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=203">
<title>Lista Mundial</title>

<style>
    .divContainer {
        width: 35px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;  
        background-color: #e1e1e1;
        font-family: verdana;   
        float: left;
    }
    .text {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: verdana;
        color: black;
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
    h4 {
        font-family: Verdana;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h4>Double click para borrar un numero</h4>
<script type="text/javascript">
    for(var i = 1; i <= 639; i++){
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");
        divTag.id = i;
        divTag.className = "divContainer";
        document.body.appendChild(divTag);
        divTag.ondblclick = function(){this.parentNode.removeChild(this)};
        var pTg = document.createElement("p");
        pTg.setAttribute("align", "center");
        pTg.className = "text";
        pTg.innerHTML = (i);
        document.getElementById(i).appendChild(pTg);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ramonfabrega/AZSy8/

For simplicity, I just tried hiding the div's clicked, but JQuery does not seem to work. So something must be off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1) jQuery wasn't loaded.
2) You were trying to bind the click event on an invalid `selector` (`divTag` instead of `div`)

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LFC3A/2/

Regarding #2 - jQuery allows you to select an element multiple ways. The most common is to use a `selector`. The majority of selectors jQuery supports are from CSS 1 - 3, though jQuery supports some of its own custom selectors (such as `div:eq`, `div:gt`, and so on...) Check out the selectors page here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Now, if your markup was:

```
<body>
    <divTag>My Custom Div Tag</divTag>
    <div>My regular DIV</div>
</body>
```

Then your original fiddle would have worked. In fact, here's an updated fiddle demonstrating that: http://jsfiddle.net/FpMAw/ (I updated your createElement to return a custom element, `divTag`)

The other way of accessing jQuery is by passing it a DOM element. Something like:

`var $body = $(document.body)` is equivalent to `var $body = $('body')`

If you reference that, you now have a jQuery object with a bunch of useful helper methods. So, in our previous example, we can now do:

`$body.css('color', 'red')`

Hopefully this helps explain a bit more why it didn't work. If you have any other questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Ok that worked, but can I know what was incorrect? I've just recently started coding through CodeHS and Codecademy so it would be nice to learn

Comment: Hi @user3495678 - Updated my answer to explain why your original code didn't work. Hopefully it helps! Have fun learning JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/j4DJ4/)</kbd>

you are not including jQuery library in the fiddle

[image]

change `$('divTag')`  to `$('div')`

Read [$( "element" )](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

---

[Start Learning](https://learn.jquery.com/)

[jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This will create and add a click handler at the same time.

```
$('<div>').click(function(e){ this.addClass('active');})
```